# Create a library (dll) with wsdls

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, wsdl

When I talked with the 3rd party to provide web service to be able to connect to them, they gave me a bunch of wsdl's( to be precise 210 wsdl's) and a url to connect to them. I used asmx file earlier but I am not sure what do I do with these wsdl's.

What I am not sure here is do I need to add all the wsdl's as "Add Service Reference" to my project and then use them or is there a different way to use them as classes in Visual Studio?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could run a batch script and generate the classes you need with the svcutil tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/generating-a-wcf-client-from-service-metadata, then add the classes to your project (and merge the configs)

Comment: @rene - I got that done. Thank you!! But it looks like I have to do that for each wsdl ;(

Comment: Yes, if you do a `forfiles` on the cmd prompt you can do all wsdls at once and then in VS you can add all *.cs files in one go. Only the config files are trickier, that might need some xslt/xml fu to get fixed

Comment: I am giving the command as 

C:\projects\MWel>svcutil.exe C:\Users\rban\Desktop\wsdl_Q12017\Cobra
ndLogin.wsdl /n:*,YodleeNet2017

This is only creating .cs files in the location specified. How can I set them to be in a library? Thank you rene